# AJAX calendar update page rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using jQuery's datepicker to show a calendar.  When the user clicks on a date, the page should render valid information (in this case a table for available seats) for that particular date.

I can see that my date is being passed with AJAX on change, but the template is never being rendered.  How does the partial know to get @schedule from the controller? What am I doing wrong?

## view

```
<p>
  Date:
  <%= text_field "Date", "", :class => 'datepicker'%>
</p>
```

## js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.datepicker').length){
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
      });

    }

    $('.datepicker').change(function(){

      $.ajax({
        data: {Date: $('.datepicker').val()},
      })
    });
  });
```

## controller

```
def show
   return unless @product

   @variants =    
   @product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values, 
   :images])

   @product_properties = @product.product_properties.includes(:property)


   @schedule = FlightSchedule.where(:date => params[:Date]).available_slots

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end

   referer = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
   if referer
     begin
       referer_path = URI.parse(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']).path
       # Fix for #2249
     rescue URI::InvalidURIError
       # Do nothing
     else
       if referer_path && referer_path.match(/\/t\/(.*)/)
         @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find_by_permalink($1)
       end
     end
   end
end
```

## js.erb

```
$('#seat_table').html('<%= escape_javascript render("seat_table")%>');
```

## partial

```
<table>
    <th> Available Times </th>
    <th colspan='5'> Available Seats </th>
    <% @schedule.each do |available| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= available.time.strftime("%l:00") %>
        </td>
        <% @product.variants_and_option_values.each_with_index do |variant, index| %>

          <td>
            <% if available.seat_available?(available, variant.option_value('seat')) %>
              <%= check_box_tag "variants[#{variant.id}]", "1" %>
              <label for="<%= ['variants', @product.id, variant.id].join('_') %>">
                <span class="variant-description">
                  <%= variant.option_value('seat') %>
                </span>
              </label>
            <% else %>
              <label for="<%= ['variants', @product.id, variant.id].join('_') %>">
                <span class="variant-description">
                  <%= variant.option_value('seat') %>
                </span>
              </label>
            <% end %>
          </td>

        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

## beginning of logs; the date is being passed and the correct action is being called.

```
    Started GET "/products/flight-simulation?Date=2014-03-31" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 14:57:57 -0400
Processing by Spree::ProductsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"Date"=>"2014-03-31", "id"=>"flight-simulation"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can see immediately is you are missing the dataType.

Change

```
$('.datepicker').change(function(){

      $.ajax({
        data: {Date: $('.datepicker').val()},
      })
    });
```

To

```
$('.datepicker').change(function(){

      $.ajax({
        data: {Date: $('.datepicker').val()},
        dataType : 'script'
      })
    });
```